# Ubuntu tool to recover just certain file types from drive with logical failure?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I'm hoping this question can help other people in the future who may be facing the same dilemma with whether to chance imaging a large drive, or just go right after individual file types (jpeg,mp3 etc)
I searched for the same question here, and could not find a specific answer.

my case-
I had a 750gb WD Scorpio Black drive with OSX 10.6.8 fail on my Macbook a few weeks ago.
It was imaged using DD by a local computer place. They basically told me to continue imaging the rest would take a month so they just saved about half the drive and called it a day. It cost me $250 to get maybe 300gb of 650. The clone drive was a 2tb WD My Passport Ultra and was formatted to Mac extj. There were two folders. "Found Files" files that still had filenames,tags etc, though many won't open and "Reconstructed Files" files that have no filename I have to sort through.

All I want to recover is audio files and pics, nothing else. My friend has a desktop setup now to use Linux recovery tools, I'm just wondering what is the safest route to go now?

I can either try and re-image the drive in chunks with the better GNU DD Rescue and use log files, or use something like Photorec.

If I know exactly what folders the files I want are in does that help?

Anyway I'm a noobie at Linux based data recovery, but I'm eager to learn. I'm 44 and was actually a hacker in high school on Apple IIE's lol 
But it's been a long time since I had to use command lines etc. Last hard drive utility I used with success was Spinrite years ago.
I appreciate any suggestions or help.
thx

Answer (score 1):

You have to try some Data Recovery tools which may help you to restore some of your old data.

[From R-tools Technology:](http://download.cnet.com/windows/R-tools%20Technology/3260-20_4-80773-1.html)

> R-Linux is a free data recovery and undelete utility for Ext2FS/3FS
>   (Linux) file systems. File recovery after power failure, system crash,
>   virus infection, or partition reformation, even for the different file
>   system. Unformat and unerase tool. The utility creates image files an
>   entire disk, partition or its part. Such drive image can be processed
>   like regular drive

You can [download 64 bit verion from here](http://download.cnet.com/R-Linux-Free-Recovery/3000-2248_4-10075543.html).

To install

```
sudo dpkg -i rli_en*.deb
```

Once open you can choose just to recover specific types Press scan from top menu then choose search by file types and uncheck all types you don't want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Maythux I'll give it a try. This Linux app will work with Mac Extended Journaled format drives? 

I've been opening up some of the DD recovered audio files as raw data in Audacity and many have gaps in them where the audio will just go silent mid way. Could this be because the data from the second half of the drive was never imaged?